# More information on Columnar or 'Column-family' data model in Cosmos DB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

The documenation states that the Cosmos DB engine "*natively supports multiple data models: key-value, documents, graphs, and **columnar*** ".

However, I can't seem to find any other information relating specifically to the columnar model.

There is also information available on the following APIs:

- DocumentDB APIs
- Table APIs
- Graph APIs

But nothing on Columnar or Column-family, as described in various summaries.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/introduction

Comment: There is no column-family API today. Probably best to provide feedback on that page, to get more details from the product team.

Comment: @JesseCarter Table api doesn't represent column-family storage. It represents key/value table entities. There's no way to have, say, a wide column of data samples in a single "row" with the table storage api (such as thousands of weather data samples).

Comment: @DavidMakogon Is the distinction that I'm missing just the ability to do querying on the additional column values then? (Table storage only allows filtering on partition key and id) The definition here definitely seems to align with the capabilities of Table Storage https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_column_store

Comment: @JesseCarter - no - that definition is fairly generic. Just consider weather data, where you have one "sample" per column, for a given weather station id (partition key) plus date (row key). A column store would allow each row to grow column-by-column as you keep adding samples (e.g. timestamp plus reading), and then query a range within those columns. Possibly thousands (or 10's of thousands) of said columns in a single related row. Not the same as a key/value store.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, that makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> can't seem to find any other information relating specifically to the columnar model

[This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/technology-choices/data-store-overview#column-family-databases) will help you understand the concept of column-family:

***You can think of a column-family database as holding tabular data with rows and columns, but the columns are divided into groups known as column families. Each column family holds a set of columns that are logically related together and are typically retrieved or manipulated as a unit. Other data that is accessed separately can be stored in separate column families. Within a column family, new columns can be added dynamically, and rows can be sparse (that is, a row doesn't need to have a value for every column).***

Besides, as David Makogon said, you can give your feedback (or comment) on that page or contact Cosmos DB team on this email (askdocdb@microsoft.com) for more details about column-family data model.

Answer (score 2):

Cosmos DB now has a Cassandra API, as of November, 2017, which provides a column-store interface. This uses the same protocol as native Cassandra, allowing you to use existing SDK's to connect to the Cassandra API.

You'll need to choose the Cassandra API when creating a new Cosmos DB account, which will be one of several APIs you can select from (the others being DocumentDB SQL, MongoDB, Gremlin, and Table).

More information about the Cassandra API is available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/cassandra-introduction).